# JSON Schema: How to check if a field contains a value

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I have a JSON schema validator where I need to check a specific field `email` to see if it's one of 4 possible emails.  Lets call the possibilities `['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']`.  Sometimes the emails contain a `\n` new line separator so I need to account for that also.  Is it possible to do a string contains method in JSON Schema?

Here is my schema without the email checks:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
        "type":"object",
        "properties": {
            "email": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
    "required": ["email"]
    }
  }
}
```

My input payload is:

```
{
  "data": {
      "email": "test3\njunktext"
      }
}
```

I would need the following payload to pass validation since it has `test3` in it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

Using [enum](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.1.2) you can define a list of valid emails:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "enum": [
            "test1",
            "test2",
            "test3"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "email"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Or with [pattern](http://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#pattern) which allows you to use a regular expression for matching a valid email:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "pattern": "test"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "email"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `enum` approach won't work because it will rule out additional text in the value.  You have to use `pattern`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have accounted for that scenario in my answer already unless I'm mistaken. The `enum` approach is good to know as well and was mentioned in case OP only needs to check against a static list of emails.

Comment: Thanks! pattern worked for me, for multiple patterns I used anyOf: [ {type: string, pattern: pattern},... etc]